# What are the 3 temperatures (composite and sensors) reported by a WD_BLACK SN770 NVMe?

Tags: ssd, temperature, nvme, sensors

I have a WD_BLACK SN770 SSD NVMe that may be running too hot under load.

So to monitor it, I installed [Western Digital Dashboard](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detailweb/p/3892) and it reports 3 temperatures:

> [image: Western Digital Dashboard]

Libre Hardware Monitor reports 3 temperatures too:

> [image]

Western Digital Dashboard shows the Composite temperature on the "State" dashboard, so it looks like this is the temperature that is used to detect overheating.

The question: What are "Composite Temperature", "Temperature Sensor 1" and "Temperature Sensor 2"? I can't find any explanation anywhere. I would like to know where the probes located on the NVMe device.

Comment: At a guess you likely have controller chip temperature, flash chip temperature and actual board (ambient) temperature. Only a guess though.

Comment: I cannot answer your question but on 3 machines my Samsung SSDs are running about 30 degrees C.

Comment: If one of the temperatures goes up while reading a lot then that is likely the controller. If one goes up significantly (with the first going up slightly) while writing then that is likely the flash chip. The third may go up slightly in either case. Or if there are multiple flash chips then it could be that you are seeing temperatures for each. It's hard to know for certain.

Comment: @Mokubai I wasn't able to measure different temperatures when writing or reading from the NVMe SSD, temperatures rised with about 20 seconds delay, which is weird.

Comment: I added a thermal pad so that the small chips (probably the controller) are now in contact with the heatsink provided with the motherboard. Temps 1 and 2 are lower by about 5 degrees. So I still can't identify each sensor but temps are less concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://borecraft.com/files/intro-composite-temp-white-paper-345213.pdf

Composite Temperature is a single, normalized temperature value that considers input from multiple temperature sensors ... while reporting to the host a single Composite Temperature value for thermal management.

... does not necessarily represent the actual temperature of any physical point within the SSD.

Composite Temperature works by monitoring multiple temperature sensors at regular intervals and comparing each current sensor value to a pre-set maximum value.

(The) NVMe recommendation of 70C is referred to as WCTEMP or Warning Compositive Temperature Threshold.

You can see that it's not a temperature in the traditional sense, but a reference that informs the host system or user ... before it (the SSD) reaches a thermal limit.

More info in the NVMe specifications: https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVMe-NVM-Express-2.0a-2021.07.26-Ratified.pdf

I tried locating some NVMe SSD's schematic or some manufacturer information, but that seems to be very rare:

[image]

That leaves the option to look at some NVMe SSD (CORSAIR Force MP510 in this case) and try locate SMD sensors to get their actual locations which I did for some random SSD. In this example the sensor seems to be located closely to a NAND chip:

[image]

For your particular SSD you'd need a high resolution picture from both sides, or examine the SSD under a microscope. For this purpose a digital microscope may be easiest. Use [this](https://nl.mouser.com/c/sensors/temperature-sensors/board-mount-temperature-sensors/?mounting%20style=SMD%2FSMT&output%20type=Digital) as reference for example.

I am not certain all sensors may actually be in the form of a separate SMD component.

It still leaves the question what Sensor corresponds with Sensor 1, Sensor 2 etc.. My best guess would be (I know you're not asking for guesses):

```
Temp   - Composite
Temp 1 - Controller
Temp 2 - NAND or board SMT (?)
```

Comment: Does Western Digital / WD_BLACK use the same definition than Intel?

Comment: It's part of the NVMe spec AFAIK.

Comment: This is interesting, could you please share it? That would mean that the brand or model of the NVMe are irrelevant in the context of this question, which I didn't expect.

Comment: AIUI manufacturer is under no obligation to even implement any temp sensors. https://nvmexpress.org/wp-content/uploads/NVMe-NVM-Express-2.0a-2021.07.26-Ratified.pdf. It's more like, if he does, he needs to play by the rules (my layman interpretation).

Answer (score 1):

The composite temperature value takes into account multiple
thresholds and sensors on the disk, and its purpose is to generate
one number which gives you a relative idea of how hot the drive is running.
The manner in which this value is computed is implementation specific
and may not represent the actual temperature of any physical point in
the NVM subsystem. The value of this field may be used to trigger
an asynchronous event in the firmware.

Source :
[Kingston SMART Attribute Details](https://media.kingston.com/support/pdf/ssd-smart-attribute.pdf).

This composite temperature value is taken as decisive in terms
of warranty claims, so is the most important number.

The values of the other sensors are taken into account when computing
the composite temperature. Unfortunately, WD does not make available
a circuit diagram of the disk, so we cannot say where
sensors 1 and 2 are positioned.

As regarding the temperatures you're seeing, they are well within the
operating parameters of the disk.

The [WD Black SN770 SSD Review](https://hothardware.com/reviews/wd-black-sn770-pcie-gen-4-nvme-ssd-review)
has this to say about the disk's temperatures under load:

> If WD’s Dashboard software is reading the sensors in the drive correctly, however, the SN770 does get pretty toasty under a sustained load, at least when Game mode is enabled. We saw a peak temperature of 81°C after two complete writes across the entire capacity of the drive in that configuration. With Game mode disabled though, which is how the drive is configured by default, temperatures are a bit lower. Performing the same test with Game mode disabled resulted in a maximum temperature of 75°C. With temps like this, if you’re going to stick the SN770 in a motherboard that doesn’t have M.2 heatsinks, make sure there’s good air-flow over the drive. Enabling Gaming Mode on the SN770 essentially disables any power-saving / sleep features, so the drive is always at the ready. Toggling the feature on and off had only minimal impact on the benchmarks we ran (as you’ll see a little later), but may theoretically minimize stutter or occasional hiccups in games that don't access the storage subsystem very often.

Typically, an SSD will report such a value and begin throttling
above 70C, often around 75C, with a later heavier throttling
state before reaching a maximum near 85C.

Comment: Could you please add a reference to the claim that composite is a computed value and not a value from a physical probe?

Comment: I added my source.

Comment: Does WD uses the same specifications that Kingston?

Comment: This is a specification of SMART attributes, which tend to be more uniform than not.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look into the drives [datasheet](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-black-ssd/product-brief-wd-black-sn770-nvme-ssd.pdf) reveals the specified operating temperature for the drive:

```
OPERATING SPECIFICATIONS:
■ Operating Temperature:
32ºF to 185ºF (0ºC to 85ºC)
■ Non-operating Temperature:
-40ºF to 185ºF (-40ºC to 85ºC)
```

60°C is well in spec. Better cooling won't hurt for prolonging the lifetime, so you could simply add a better fan or a heat spreader

Comment: Thanks for this answer but that doesn't explain which sensor is reporting the temperature of the chip, the controller or the PCB board.